# Java Spring boot how to manage 2 exchange server resources with OAUth2 client on the other?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

[image]I am trying to add an OAuth2 token to my requests in order to secure exchanges. With another server.
spec `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`

I know that this code does not work, but I have not been able to find complete examples

add a header request token to access another secure server

```java
@Configuration
public class OAuth2SecurityConfigClient {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

public void logResourceServiceResponse() {

    webClient.get()
            .uri("{$spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.issuer-uri}")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class)
            .map(string
                    -> "Retrieved using Client Credentials Grant Type: " + string)
            .subscribe(logger::info);
}

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        clientRegistrations,
                        new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("idsvr");
        return WebClient.builder()
                .filter(oauth)
                .build();
    }
}

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Barear" + webclient.getToken());

public String[] getUserAll() {
        return localApiClient
.head(headers )
                .get()
                .uri(baseUrl+"/users" )
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String[].class)
                .block(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
    }
```

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-name=client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-id=KEY
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-secret=SKEY
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.scope=openid
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.issuer-uri=XXX/idserver
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.authorization-uri=XXX/idserver/connect/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.token-uri=XXX/idserver/connect/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.jwk-set-uri=XXX/idserver/.well-known/jwks
```

to sum up, I therefore want to add to all my applications calling a 2nd server a valid authentication token of the bearen type with OAuth2

Answer (score 0):

Is you resource-server 1 accessing resources from resource-server 2 in its own name or on behalf of an authenticated user?

The answer to this question will determine the flow to use:

- in first case resource-server 1 is actually a **client** and has to contact authorization-server to get an access-token of its own using **client-credentials** flow.
- in second case, resource-server 1 can authorize its own request to resource-server 2 with the Bearer access-token it recieved (and which should be available from `Authentication` instance in security-context)

Of course the configuration to apply is quite different depending on your actual case.

#### Configuring WebClient with client-credentials

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.idsvr.issuer-uri=XXX/idserver

spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-id=KEY
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.client-secret=SKEY
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.idsvr.authorization-grant-type=client_credentials
```

```java
webClient.get()
    .uri(baseUrl + "/users")
    .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId("idsvr"))
    .retrieve()
    ....
```

#### Forward access-token

```java
final var auth = (AbstractOAuth2TokenAuthenticationToken<OAuth2Token>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
webClient.get()
    .uri(baseUrl + "/users")
    .headers(headers -> headers.setBearerAuth(auth.getToken().getTokenValue()))
    .retrieve()
    ....
```